# Why does python indent my print statement when I create a new line before starting the print with a variable?

Tags: python, printing

I hope that makes sense. I want the print on a new line so I put "\n" before starting the print with an inputted variable and it automatically indents a space or two. How do I stop it from doing this?
This is the code:
print("\n",employee,"worked no overtime.")

Comment: The sep option of print() makes space between the values. Just make the first two strings one as `print( '\nemployee', 'worked no overtime.')`.

Comment: employee is a variable though

Comment: Ah~~, my fault. Then you can use formatted string for the first string as `print( '\n{}'.format(employee), 'worked no overtime.')`. I think we can make a formatted string for all of them as `print('\n{} worked no overtime'.format(employee))`